# Audit table to have deleted record

Tags: java, jpa, audit

Using

> HistoryPolicy

and

> DescriptorCustomizer

How can I have a record inserted to "audit table" when data is *deleted* from "main table" ?

Currently, I am working on a simple user table as the "main table" and I have the following as the details :

A. Java coding:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(com.sfw.entity.TrackingListener.class)
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable,DescriptorCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) {
        String tblNm = descriptor.getTableName();
        String trckTblNm = tblNm.substring(0,tblNm.indexOf("_")) + "_TT";
        HistoryPolicy policy = new HistoryPolicy();
        policy.addHistoryTableName(tblNm,trckTblNm);
        policy.addStartFieldName("TRACK_START");
        policy.addEndFieldName("TRACK_END");
        descriptor.setHistoryPolicy(policy);
    }
}
```

B. Audit table column

```
| cre_tms             | upd_tms             | upd_usr | version | usr_act 
| track_start         | track_end           | user_id | username
```

C. Sample data when a new user is **created**

```
| 2012-11-22 13:28:08 | 2012-11-22 13:33:23 | demo2   |       1 | A       
| 2012-11-22 13:28:08 | 2012-11-22 13:33:23 |      12 | demo3
```

D. Sample data after a user is **created then updated**

```
| 2012-11-22 13:28:08 | 2012-11-22 13:33:23 | demo2   |       1 | A       
| 2012-11-22 13:28:08 | 2012-11-22 13:33:23 |      12 | demo3
| 2012-11-22 13:28:08 | 2012-11-22 13:33:23 | demo2   |       2 | U       
| 2012-11-22 13:33:23 | NULL                |      12 | demo3updated
```

E. Sample data after a user is **created , updated , then deleted**

```
| 2012-11-22 13:28:08 | 2012-11-22 13:33:23 | demo2   |       1 | A       
| 2012-11-22 13:28:08 | 2012-11-22 13:33:23 |      12 | demo3
| 2012-11-22 13:28:08 | 2012-11-22 13:33:59 | demo2   |       2 | U       
| 2012-11-22 13:33:23 | 2012-11-22 13:33:59 |      12 | demo3updated
```

F. **Desired output** for the audit table

```
| 2012-11-22 13:28:08 | 2012-11-22 13:33:23 | demo2   |       1 | A       
| 2012-11-22 13:28:08 | 2012-11-22 13:33:23 |      12 | demo3
| 2012-11-22 13:28:08 | 2012-11-22 13:33:59 | demo2   |       2 | U       
| 2012-11-22 13:33:23 | 2012-11-22 13:33:59 |      12 | demo3updated
| 2012-11-22 13:28:08 | 2012-11-22 13:34:59 | demo2   |       3 | D       
| 2012-11-22 13:33:59 | 2012-11-22 13:34:59 |      12 | demo3updated
```

When a record is deleted, it just update the track_end field (Point E)
The desired output is to have one more record inserted with different version (i use @Version for this)
For the usr_act , the value is passed from a textfield in xhtml

Is this possible at all?